# How to pass command line script variables to pm2 configuration JSON

Tags: java, json, bash, monitoring, pm2

I am trying to set up PM2 for our existing Java applications.  The line in the start.sh file that runs the services is as follows:

```
exec nohup "$JAVACMD" -jar $JVM_OPTS  $CLASSPATH server $ENV_NAME/config.yml
```

Where $JAVACMD is java, $JVM_OPTS is the JVM options set earlier in the script, $ENV_NAME is the environment the script runs in, and $CLASSPATH is the path to the path to the service jar that contains all the dependencies and code.  I'm trying to set this up using a pm2 config JSON file, so when the service is started, it is added to PM2.  My issue is that I do not know how to pass these variables to the arg parameter in the config file.  Obviously, I can hard code $JAVACMD and $CLASSPATH to be their respective values.  However, I cannot do that with $JVM_OPTS, as this contains many different parameters, some of which have been tokenized.  The variable looks like this:

```
JVM_OPTS='"-Djava.security.auth.login.config='"$HOME"'/config/SQLJDBCDriver.conf" "-Djava.security.krb5.conf='"$HOME"'/config/krb5.conf"'  #it is much longer than this, but this gives an idea of the format
```

So far, my pm2 config file looks like this:

```
{
  "apps" : [
    {
      "name" : "search-service",
      "script" : "java",
      "args" : [
        "-jar $CLASSPATH $JVM_OPTS server $CLASSPATH $ENV_NAME/config.yml"
      ],
      "out_file" : "~/logs/search-service.log",
      "error_file" : "~/logs/search-service.log",
      "log_date_format" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the line in the start.sh script to call it is:

```
pm2 start ./pm2_config.json
```

However, when the I call ./start.sh followed by pm2 ls, I see that this service has errored out in pm2.  pm2 show gives me the following:

```
| status            │ errored                                                   │
│ name              │ search-service                                            │
│ version           │ N/A                                                       │
│ restarts          │ 15                                                        │
│ uptime            │ 0                                                         │
│ script path       │ /usr/bin/java                                             │
│ script args       │ -jar $CLASSPATH $JVM_OPTS server $ENV_NAME/config.yml     │
│ error log path    │ /home/test/logs/search-service.log                        │
│ out log path      │ /home/test/logs/search-service-svc.log                    │
│ pid path          │ /home/test/.pm2/pids/search-service-202.pid               │
│ interpreter       │ none                                                      │
│ interpreter args  │ N/A                                                       │
│ script id         │ 202                                                       │
│ exec cwd          │ /home/test/search-service/bin                             │
│ exec mode         │ fork_mode                                                 │
│ node.js version   │ N/A                                                       │
│ node env          │ N/A                                                       │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                                                         │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                                                         │
│ created at        │ N/A
```

When I try passing in the variable in the start line:

```
pm2 start ./pm2_config.json --$JVM_OPTS
```

Then all that happens is that the script outputs the version number of pm2. I've also tried this with "$JVM_OPTS" and "-$JVM_OPTS", with the same result.

Based on this, I know that the variables are not being replaced in the config file.  Is there any way to do this?